# Doctrine QueryBuilder cuts the result when I use orderBy

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, symfony-3.4

I have a large repository method which generates a regular query at backend, some of the parameters I pass to that repository method are the max-results, firs-result, order-by and order-by-dir in order to control the total of records to display, pagination and the order of the records. The problem is when I am in some configuration ex.(4th page, max-results:10, first-result:40), this should give me the 40th to 50th records of +1000 records in database but only is returning -10 records from +1000 records.

> QB Code

```
....
return $total ? //this is a bool parameter to find out if I want the records or the records amount
                $qb
                    ->select($qb->expr()->count('ec.id'))
                    ->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult() :
                $qb//these are the related entities all are joined by leftJoin of QB
                    ->addSelect('c')
                    ->addSelect('e')
                    ->addSelect('pr')
                    ->addSelect('cl')
                    ->addSelect('ap')
                    ->addSelect('com')
                    ->addSelect('cor')
                    ->addSelect('nav')
                    ->addSelect('pais')
                    ->addSelect('tarifas')
                    ->addSelect('transitario')
                    ->orderBy(isset($options['sortBy']) ? $options['sortBy'] : 'e.bl', isset($options['sortDir']) ? $options['sortDir'] : 'asc')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->setMaxResults(isset($options['limit']) ? $options['limit'] : 10)
                    ->setFirstResult(isset($options['offset']) ? $options['offset'] : 0)
                    ->getArrayResult();
```

> Scenario 1: QueryBuilder with orderBy and database

**QB:** In this case the result is only one entity with the expected data, but only one entity not 10 when exists more than 1000 records
**DB:** In this case I get 10 records but with the same entity(the same output from QB but repeated 10 times)

> Scenario 2: QueryBuilder with out orderBy and database

**QB:** In this case the result is as expected 10 records filtered from +1000 records

**DB:** In this case the result is as expected 10 records

The only problem in this scenario is that I can't order my results using the QB.

> Environment description

- Symfony: 3.4.11
- PostgeSQL: 9.2
- PHP 7.2
- OS: Ubuntu Server 16.04 x64

Why doctrine/postgres are giving me that kind of result?

There is no Exceptions, miss configurations its only cuts the results when I use orderBy

Comment: Have you verified that the generated SQL-statement in the profiler, work as expected. Are the ORDER BY, LIMIT and OFFSET values the way you would expect

Comment: yes, I did getSQL on query object and executed on server; the results are as I described in my post

Comment: I guess its because you are selecting related entities too via left join and i guess to one to many in nature you get multiple result per entity with order by you get same records while as compared in absence of order the records are same but not sorted means you have duplicate records due to joins

Comment: Yes, I already noticed that, I made a leftJoin with a OTM attribute. The issue is that doctrine figures it out that is all the records are repeated from the same entity during the Hydratation process. The issue was never with the order by, it was always with the OTM join and the duplicated results; I just was so stressed that I did not notice that detail. I just removed the join and all worked fine, in the other now I get the join info from other way. Thanks for your comment, answer the question if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from comments posting this as an answer

---

I guess its because you are selecting related entities via left join, So you will be getting multiple results per main entity (due one to many relationships) but not in a sorted manner but when you do order by on your result set, the duplicates shows up in a same row, In absence of order by the the duplicates were still there but not in same row as unsorted results so you haven't noticed/considered them as duplicate record.

What i think as a workaround for your case is select only your main entity lets A in query builder don't select related ones `addSelect(...)` and use [lazy loading](https://www.doctrine-project.org/2009/05/29/doctrine-lazy-loading.html) when you want to display your desired results from related entities.